# Does CSharpMath support Avalonia 11.0.4?

Tags: c#, math, avalonia

*Update:* The minimal example for the question has been added at [this repository](https://github.com/accountforquestiononstackexchange/CSharpMathWithAvalonia11.0.4).

I am trying to make a C# Avalonia application for displaying mathematical formulae as part of some presentation software I was asked to write. Although there are lots of good existing solutions for mathematical presentations, C# was chosen because it allows embedded OpenGl windows that can run more complicated simulations than WebGl by capitalizing on native hardware. Despite having used the term presentation, self-guided demonstration may be more accurate as the user would download and application and navigate through the content at his leisure.

To render the mathematics, I looked at the [CSharpMath](https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath) library on Github by VeryBadCat who goes by the username @william-jokusch or user:246568 on this forum. I was able to get the demo running for Avalonia framework 10.0.0, which typeset beautifully much better than MathJax or Katex in my humble opinion. Unfortunately, the rest of my user interface expects to run with Avalonia 11.0.4. I read [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Breaking-Changes) that there were breaking changes from Avalonia 10.0.0 to 11.0.4, which included renaming Avalonia.IVisual to Avalonia.Visual.

When I run `dotnet build`, the build succeeds, but I am left with a puzzling message.

> Could not extract the MVID from "obj/Debug/net6.0/refint/Mel.dll". Are you sure it is a reference assembly?

Then, when I type `dotnet run`, I receive a runtime error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Avalonia.Visuals, Version=0.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8d484a7012f9a8b'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Avalonia.Visuals, Version=0.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8d484a7012f9a8b'
   at Mel.Views.MainWindow.!XamlIlPopulate(IServiceProvider , MainWindow )
   at Mel.Views.MainWindow.!XamlIlPopulateTrampoline(MainWindow )
   at Mel.Views.MainWindow.InitializeComponent(Boolean loadXaml, Boolean attachDevTools) in ~/Mel.Avalonia/Mel/Avalonia.Generators/Avalonia.Generators.NameGenerator.AvaloniaNameSourceGenerator/Mel.Views.MainWindow.g.cs:line 23
   at Mel.Views.MainWindow..ctor() in ~/Mel.Avalonia/Mel/Views/MainWindow.axaml.cs:line 9
   at Mel.App.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted() in ~/Mel.Avalonia/Mel/App.axaml.cs:line 19
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.SetupUnsafe()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.Setup()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.SetupWithLifetime(IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
   at Avalonia.ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetimeExtensions.StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(AppBuilder builder, String[] args, ShutdownMode shutdownMode)
   at Mel.Program.Main(String[] args) in ~/Mel.Avalonia/Mel/Program.cs:line 12
```

Do I need to try and include this file in an sln?

If it is helpful, I am running my code on Debian Linux and developing with Visual Studio Code. I also ran a windows virtual machine and had the same error, so I do not believe this error depends on the operating system.

Comment: Remember that your post needs to stand on its own, even if external links turn into 404s: if you have a [mcve], put it in your post, and then link out to the (potentially far more, or even complete) project in some third party location. (even if github's not likely to disappear any time soon, only add links [_in addition_ to having the code in your post](/help/how-to-ask), "Help others reproduce the problem" section)